# Stream batches of data from GitHub urls one by one after requests.get

Tags: python, iteration, github-api

I'm trying to parse URLs one by one, considering that each call to read() will return a portion of data. I have one owner (GitHub account), one or multiples repositories and one or more resources (issues, commits, etc.). The class must iterate of every repository and resource combination as the user calls read()
multiple times. The problem is that it doesn't iterate over every combination between owner, repositories, and resources. Here is my code until now:

```
import requests

class GitHub():

    def __init__(self, owner, repositories, resources):
        self.owner = owner
        self.repositories = repositories
        self.resources = resources

    def read(self):
        for rep in self.repositories:
            for res in self.resources:
                url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/{}/{}/{}'.format(self.owner, rep, res)
                result = requests.get(url)
                if result.status_code == 200:
                    json_res = result.json()
                    return json_res
                else:
                    print(result.text)
                    print(result.status_code)

gh = GitHub('example', ['example1', 'example2'], ['issues','pulls'])
data = gh.read()
```

**UPDATE**

```
class GitHub():

    def __init__(self, owner, repositories, resources):
        self.owner = owner
        self.repositories = repositories
        self.resources = resources

    def create_list(self):
        for rep in self.repositories:
            for res in self.resources:
                url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/{}/{}/{}'.format(self.owner, rep, res)
                result = requests.get(url)
                if result.status_code == 200:
                    json_res = result.json()
                    print(json_res)
                else:
                    print(result.text)
                    print(result.status_code)
                    break
                yield

gh = GitHub('moby', ['moby', 'buildkit'], ['issues','pulls'])
data = gh.create_list()
while data is not None:
    try:
        next(data)
        data = gh.create_list()
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

I just managed to arrive at this form of the code. Now, when I try to execute the code, it iterates over the same URL (`.../moby/moby/issues`), without taking the next value from the `self.resources` (in `create_list` method). Where am I wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the perceived problem here. Given your example I see it generating requests to `/repos/example/example1/issues`, `/repos/example/example1/pulls`, `/repos/example/example2/issues` and `/repos/example/example2/pulls`. This is all the combinations. What else are you expecting?

Comment: @cody yes, I know, but the code didn't manage to request for all the combinations. Please check the update

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're using `yield` so you're attempting to create a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), which allows you iterate over the items one at a time. But there are two problems:

1. You're `yield`ing no generated value
2. You're calling `create_list()` as if it produces all of its elements at once.

In the following, I've changed the `yield` to generate a dict with the url and result for the current item. Then I iterate over the values with `for`, printing each item's url and the number of elements in the result returned from GitHub:

```
import requests

class GitHub():

    def __init__(self, owner, repositories, resources):
        self.owner = owner
        self.repositories = repositories
        self.resources = resources

    def create_list(self):
        for rep in self.repositories:
            for res in self.resources:
                url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/{}/{}/{}'.format(self.owner, rep, res)
                result = requests.get(url)
                if result.status_code == 200:
                    yield {'url': url, 'result': result.json()}

gh = GitHub('moby', ['moby', 'buildkit'], ['issues','pulls'])
for result in gh.create_list():
    print('url: {}\tlen(result): {}'.format(result['url'], len(result['result'])))
```

Output:

```
url: https://api.github.com/repos/moby/moby/issues      len(result): 30
url: https://api.github.com/repos/moby/moby/pulls       len(result): 30
url: https://api.github.com/repos/moby/buildkit/issues  len(result): 30
url: https://api.github.com/repos/moby/buildkit/pulls   len(result): 8
```